# pnp m365 cli script fails when trying to log in using a custom application registration

Tags: azure, docker, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I need to use the pnp m365 cli to add / remove users in AAD.

So I'd like to do things like:

```
 m365 aad user add --userName "johndoe@somedomain.com"
 m365 aad user remove --userName "johndoe@somedomain.com"
 m365 aad user recyclebinitem restore --userName "johndoe@somedomain.com"
```

I have tried to follow the instructions here:
https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/user-guide/using-own-identity/#login-and-consent

Created a new application registration that looks like this:
[image]

And this is what I have so far for the API permissions:

[image]

I'm running in a docker container that was created like so:

```
FROM m365pnp/cli-microsoft365:latest
ENV CLIMICROSOFT365_AADAPPID="clientIDFormyCustomApp"
ENV OFFICE365CLI_TENANT="mytenantId"
```

Inside the container, i have a powershell script with just one line so far:

m365 login --authType secret --secret $applicationsecret

When i try to run it, i get the following error:

```
PS /workspaces/IntegrationTesting> ./createUser.ps1
Error: unauthorized_client: 700016 - [2023-04-10 20:52:24Z]: AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'myapplicationid' was not found in the directory 'Microsoft'. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.
```

**What I've tried so far:**

I checked to make sure that the environment variables are set properly ... and they are.
Ran "env" from a bash terminal and I can see that they are set.
I also check the docker env and they are set too.
I made sure the secret is the right value as well.  In fact I created a new secret.

Not sure what else to check. Do I have the right API Permissions to add / remove azure AD users?